# How to open Hue portal from guest OS?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-manager

I have installed cloudera dist of hadoop in virtual box. Guest OS is Mac OS. I can connect to vm via ssh and send files via scp.

How can i open Hue portal from Mac if the ip to VM is 19.168.1.1 ?

I am using a 4GB mac air, its very slow in VM. Tried launching http://192.168.1.1:8888, but its not opening.

Answer (score 1):

You must start the Hue service via Cloudera Manager (which requires having at least 6GB in the VM, I believe to start from the Cloudera Express Icon on the Desktop)

Last time I used CDH, none of the Hadoop services start by default, so even if you could get to Hue, I'm not sure if it would be useful for anything without starting at least HDFS, YARN, and Hive (which together themselves require about a total 4GB of memory to run smoothly)

Comment: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-13-x/topics/cloudera_quickstart_vm.html#xd_583c10bfdbd326ba-3ca24a24-13d80143249--7f9d__section_d3z_wtv_ls shows 4GB minimum for the VM.

Comment: Cloudera Express (which runs Cloudera Manager) requires 8